# How to create table in lower case name - JavaDB/Derby?

Tags: java, derby, javadb

Is it possible to create table and it's name in lower case using JavaDB/Derby? To check if table exists I'm using:

```
ResultSet rs = dbmd.getTables(null, "APP", "user_properties", null);
if (!rs.next()) {/*do something*/};
```

But table name 'user_properties' must mach the case in catalog.

Comment: cant you use create table table_name ....?

Comment: If I do `st.execute("CREATE TABLE user_properties");` in Schema 'APP' it is recorded as 'USER_PROPERTIES' - in upper case.. I want it to be in lower case. That's not a very big problem, just asking if it is possible :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Derby follows the ANSI standard which requires unquoted identifiers to be folded to uppercase. 
So, the following statement:

```
create table user_properties
(
   id integer not null
);
```

will create a table with then name `USER_PROPERTIES` and a column named `ID`.

You can force Derby to store lower case (or actually mixed cased) names by using quoted identifiers:

```
create table "user_properties"
(
   "id" integer not null
);
```

will create a table with then name `user_properties` and a column named `id`.

When you use quoted identifiers (aka "delimited identifiers") they become case-sensitive, so the second table must **always** be referenced using double quotes.

The statement `select * from user_properties` will **not** work if the table was created with the second statement. You *have* to always quote it: `select * from "user_properties"`.

Using quoted identifiers is usually causing *much* more trouble than it's worth. If you never ever quote your identifiers you can safely use the upper case name in the call to `getTables()`

Comment: Yes, that worked for me. MySQL syntax is a bit easier comparing to this situation, but it cost too much to use commercially :) I think I will stay with upper cases and without quotes.

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis: actually if you run MySQL in ANSI mode it behaves pretty much the same.