# PostgreSQL and Apache Derby proper column name in JAVA Dao

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, derby

I have Dao layer on Java.
When I call `insert` method i want get "id" of inserted row.
Im doing like this

```
connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL, new String[] { "id" }))
```

All works fine in Postgres. But when i try doing same in Derby(in my integration test) ive got this `java.sql.SQLException:Field "id" doesnt exist.`
When i change to this     `new String[] { "ID" })` - Derby works fine but PostgreSQL write same bug `java.sql.SQLException:Field "id" doesnt exist.`
I dont want to use this answer coz i have to rewrite many requests: [How to create table in lower case name - JavaDB/Derby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156565/how-to-create-table-in-lower-case-name-javadb-derby)

Can some one help me?

Comment: Try `prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)`

Comment: Have tried. Works fine with Postgre, But Derby: `java.sql.SQLException:Field "id" doesnt exist.`